# GeoJSON data saving but returns undefined when queried

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, geojson, openlayers-3

I have the following schema

```
    var RaceSchema = new Schema({
    account: {
        _id: String,
    name: String,
    country: String
    },
    raceName:  String,
    raceStartTime: Date,
    timezone: Number,
    trackTimeStart: Date,
    trackTimeFinish: Date,
    sponserImageURL: Array,     
    map: {
        center: Array,
        course: Object,
        zoomLevel: Number
    },
    boats: [{
            _id: String,
            handicaps: [{                   
                                name: String,
                    division: Number,
                    rating: Number,
                    correctedTime: Number,
                    place: Number
                            }]
    }],
    dtg: Number,
    eta: Date,
    finishTime: Date,
    socialMedia: [{
                    name: String,
                    link: String
    }],
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: new Date },
    updatedAt: Date
}, {
    collection: 'race'
});
```

Which I am using to store GeoJson data along with some other information as seen in the schema. I am saving the data in the following format (its the response that i get from the server on saving)

```
{
    "_id": "562bc48bfde8999f2995e61d",
    "raceStartTime": "2015-10-29T17:48:00.000Z",
    "trackTimeStart": "2015-10-24T17:48:00.000Z",
    "trackTimeFinish": "2015-10-24T17:48:00.000Z",
    "raceName": "Test ",
    "timezone": -4.5,
    "__v": 1,
    "updatedAt": "2015-10-24T17:49:16.912Z",
    "createdAt": "2015-10-24T17:39:45.587Z",
    "socialMedia": [],
    "boats": [{
        "_id": "55f6c2d39a2496d01d000002",
        "handicaps": []
    }],
    "map": {
        "center": [78.4651562, 17.4079808],
        "course": "{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[8639830.18113004,2037505.4259696582],[8738281.073561348,1972075.3297575472],[8619650.805662755,1928659.0976915671],[8645333.647166574,1981859.2693780498],[8598248.437742906,2021606.5240863415]]}",
        "zoomLevel": 8
    },
    "sponserImageURL": [],
    "account": {
        "_id": "55a7c944d65763c23d11dd96",
        "name": "Huy Tran"
    },
    "id": "562bc48bfde8999f2995e61d"
}
```

I am saving the data for **map.course** as an object as seen from my schema in the same format that i receive from open layers api. This I am guessing is causing my **findByIdAndRemove(id, callback);** to return a

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '562bc2b5fde8999f2995e61c' of undefined
```

How can I fix this issue so that I can perform other operations other than save on this schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be saving `map.course` as a `String` (of JSON data), not as an `Object`.

If that is GeoJSON created by `ol.format.GeoJSON`, consider using [`writeFeatureObject`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html#writeFeatureObject) instead of [`writeFeature`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html#writeFeature). They return the same result, but the first is an actual JS object and the seconds is a String with JSON.

Comment: Thanks, this was a part of the problem. I was also not properly defining my action inside my router.